# FileObject read works like write

Tags: python, file-io, seek

Let's see simple piece of code:

```
import os

f = open('test.bin', 'wb')
f.write('X')
f.close()
# test.bin - X

f = open('test.bin', 'r+b')

f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
f.write('AB')
# test.bin - XAB

f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
f.write('Y')
# test.bin - YAB

print f.read(1)
# test.bin - YBB and prints B 0_o whhyyy?

f.close()
```

Why in that case read method works like write??
I use Python 2.5 and 2.7 for windows download from official site.

Comment: when using python 2.6 on linux, `test.bin` contains `YAB` at the end and the last read returns `A`. however, python 2.6 on windows results in `YBB` and the last read returns `B`.

Comment: Very strange, any ideas?

Comment: i seem to remember that files opened in `'r+'` mode under windows did not behave the same as on un*x due to a difference in implementation in the `fopen()` function (which calls windows `CreateFile()` under the hood). unfortunately, i can't find my source again... eventually try opening the file in using mode `'w+b'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put

```
f.flush()
```

after you write 'Y' subsequent read(1) reads the correct value (in this case 'A').

So my guess is that on windows read() doesn't force buffers flush while on *nix it does.